# Term for "the class of landlords"

Tags: single-word-requests, loanwords, french, foreign-phrases

I have heard in several spoken discussions a term (which sounds kind of French and is maybe related to the English verb "rent") for the class of landlords - people who live off renting out properties or lending money for interest, as opposed to productive work.

I don't know how to spell it and was unsuccessful in guessing. Any idea what that might be?

Here is a discussion in which it was mentioned several times by both conversants:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cMuIoIidVWI#t=23m22s

Comment: Can you spell it how you *think* it's spelled? I get that you don't seem to think it's correct but we may be able to recognize the word by sounding it out phonetically from what you think it is.

Comment: Perhaps *rentier*?

Comment: Lessor? Boniface? Laird? Yes, as Catjia suggests, some idea of what your research has uncovered would be helpful.

Comment: The *bourgeois*, enemy of the *proletariat*? The *nobility* or *aristrocracy*?

Comment: @Catija edited my question

Comment: The word the guy in the video uses at the timestamp you linked to is indeed [@StoneyB's *rentiers*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/338514/term-for-the-class-of-landlords#comment778800_338514).

Comment: @StoneyB Yes :)

Comment: @rapt the answer is pretty much a direct phonetic mapping from what the speaker says so it's strange you didn't hit on "rentier definition" fairly quickly. Are you sure that this isn't a way to direct us to revolutionary politic speeches on YouTube ?

Comment: @k1eran Considering the OP had to be prompted to post the content, I don't really think that's a fair accusation.

Comment: @k1eran Haha if you listen to how Chris Hedges pronounced it (here or in the first video, I don't remember), it sounded like "rontie" or "rauntie" - at least to me... Google was not able to correct me. But from the context I guessed it was something about rent.

Comment: Of course, many people will use the term "slumlord", whether merited or not.

Comment: @Catija and rapt.  okay I didn't realise link was added later, and I was only joking anyway. No offence intended!

Comment: @k1eran All in good spirits :) Hopefully I did not overly upset any rentier out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As guessed by StoneyB in the comments, the word is "rentiers" - a word that English borrows from French, and which derives from the same French root word as the English verb "rent," as you correctly deduced.**

> **Rentier**
>
> Pronunciation: /ˌränˈtyā/
>
> NOUN
>
> A person living on income from property or investments.
>
> **Origin**
>
> French, from *rente* ('dividend').

Source: [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/rentier)

Comment: Thanks, is `/ˌränˈtyā/` also how it is pronounced in French? As I explained above, I had a hard time to guess the spelling because I heard it several times pronounced differently, or at least I thought so.

Comment: The French version is actually spelled "rentière," and the second *r* is pronounced at the the throat. The vowels are pronounced roughly the same as in the English version. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20pronounce%20rentier%20in%20french

Comment: @Justin French *rentière* is feminine (pronounced /ʁɑ̃.tjɛʁ/. Masculin is *rentier* pronounced /ʁɑ̃.tje/.

Comment: @Laure - Thank you for the correction! French is definitely one of my weaker languages - my study of it is almost completely limited to the cognates between French and English.